# asp.mvc3 @Html.DropDownListFor<> not working correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, postback, viewmodel, html-helper

I have a strange issue with dropdown list in ASP.MVC3.
I have a view model that looks like this:

```cs
public class dto{
  [Key]
  public Int32 ClientID { get; set; }
  [Required, MaxLength(50)]
  public Name{get;set;}

  public int ClientTypeID { get; set; }

  public SelectList ClientTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Razor use:

```cs
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientTypeID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ClientTypeID,Model.ClientTypes)
</div>
```

In the controller i fill the ClientTypes with data.
When i use it to create a new dto object it works fine, and the selection is transfered back to controler and saved.
It also works fine when i use it to Edit an existing object, the proper value is selected when the page opens.

Problem is, when i change the selection, it does not get posted back to controler, while other edited values are returned correctly.

Can anyone point me in the direction of the problem?

thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in my code I do something like this - in the ViewModel I've got an IEnumerable:

```
public IEnumerable<Choice> Choices { get; set; }
```

which gets populated back in the controller action.

and `Choice` looks something like

```
public class Choice
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

and in my ViewModel I've also got a member that looks like this:

```
public int TheChoice { get; set; }
```

and then in my View I've got something that looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TheChoice, new SelectList(Model.Choices, "Id", "Text", @Model.TheChoice))
```

and that seems to work pretty well.

Are you doing something differently that that?

Comment: i seem to be missing the last @Model.TheChoice part. But adding the eqvivalent did not change things. It still works in all the scenarios except to send the updated value back to Controller.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you put a breakpoint in the controller action and examine the viewmodel argument sent back from the view, you see that your ClientID value in the viewmodel argument has the *old* value and not the *new* one, right?

Comment: not the cliendID, but the ClientTypeID, but yes, that is correct. I can see all the values from VM, and the text fields are updated, just the ClientTypeID is not. it is still the old value. I have concluded that means it gets sent there properly, and back again, just is not updated there. And I have no idea why.

Comment: Strange. Wondering if there's a mapping problem with your model.  If you change the signature on the action to look like `public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection collection)` and then comment out the body of the code and just do a `return View();` instead, drop a breakpoint on that and examine the FormCollection parameter, do you see the new value there in the debugger or the old one?  In the watch window those values can be found under collection->base->base->_entriesArray.

Comment: You don't happen to have an `@HiddenFor(model => model.ClientTypeID)` in your view do you?  That would cause the viewmodel property to not get updated.

Comment: No, no @HiddenFor, and in the collection i still see the old value. The strangest thing is that it works when i create a new object, and not when i am doing an update. i am using the same partial view in both scenarios.

Comment: Consider posting a little more code.  I don't see anything in what you've posted above other than what I mentioned.